# HTML, CSS. Trying to get two slideshows to play simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get two slideshows to play simultaneously with each other going at the same speed. I have Slide2 working, however, my Slide1 isn't working at all. I have been wondering how I could fix this.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<head>
<title> Welcome to Sunsplash Festival </title>
</style>
<body>
<audio controls>
<source src="ReadyForWar.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a href="tickets.html">Tickets</a> </li>
<li> <a href="acts.html">Performers</a> </li>
<li> <a href="location.html">Location</a> </li>sitemap.html"
<li> <a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a> </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

<div>
<img class="Slide2" img src="img/b.jpg" alt="Festival Night">
<img class="Slide2" img src="img/c.jpg" alt="Festival Party">
</div>

<div>
<img class="Slide1" img src="img/a.jpg" alt="Festival Girl">
<img class="Slide1" img src="img/MusicPower.jpg" alt="Through The Power Of Music">
</div>

<div>
<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Slide2");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 1500); 
}
</script>
</div>

<div>
<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carouse2();

function carouse2() {
var i;
var x = document/getElementsByClassName("Slide1");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].style.display = "none";
}
myIndex++;
if (myIndex > x.length) (myIndex = 1)
x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
setTimeout(carouse2, 2000);
}
</script>
<div>

<div>
<footer>
<small> Copy: 2017 Sunsplash Festival. All Rights Reserved </small>
<a href="sitemap.html" title="Links to all the pages on this website">Sitemap</a>
</footer>
</div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
.Slide1{
    height: 741px;
    width: 1406px;
}

.Slide2{
    height: 741px;
    width: 1406px;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #000000;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

body {
    background-color: #90EE90;
    ]

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method `carouse2` you used parentheses around `myindex = 1` instead of curly braces and you are using the same variable across both functions.

Also, in `carouse2` you had a different timeout before the method was called again. I replaced both with the same variable, so that you only have to change 1 number.

I removed the div around the script element, because that was obsolete and combined the two blocks into one (in that way the browser renders more quickly).

And last but not least, to ensure you are not making any mistakes, `carouse2` is now doing the work for Slide2, and `carousel` is targeting Slide1, because it is easier to recognise which function enables which slide.

I rewrote your code and this should work:

```
<script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    var speed = 1500;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Slide");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
           x[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) {
            myIndex = 1
        }
        x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        setTimeout(carousel, speed); 
    }

    var mySecondIndex = 0;
    carouse2();

    function carouse2() {
        var j;
        var y = document/getElementsByClassName("Slide2");
        for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
            y[j].style.display = "none";
        }
        mySecondIndex++;
        if (mySecondIndex > y.length) {
            mySecondIndex = 1
        }
        y[mySecondIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(carouse2, speed);
    }
</script>
```

Let me know if this works!